# Can WebDeploy Backup on Application Level Not the Whole Site?

Tags: iis, backup, webdeploy

I have successfully setup an auto-backup when I deploy thru WebDeploy.

However, when it archives, it zips the whole "Default Web Site".

What I am looking for is a way to set the auto-backup to archive only that application.

**Update1**: My Current Setting

PS> Get-BackupSettings -SiteName "Default Web Site/Service1"

```
CanSetContinueSyncOnFailure : False
ExcludedProviders           : {appPoolEnable32Bit, setAcl, appPoolPipeline, createApp...}
BackupPath                  : {SitePathParent}\{siteName}_snapshots
ContinueSyncOnFailure       : False
CanAddExcludedProviders     : False
NumberOfBackups             : 5
Enabled                     : True
SiteName                    : Default Web Site/Service1
CanSetEnabled               : False
CanSetNumberOfBackups       : False
```

---

PS> Get-BackupSettings -SiteName "Default Web Site"

```
CanSetContinueSyncOnFailure : False
ExcludedProviders           : {appPoolEnable32Bit, setAcl, appPoolPipeline, createApp...}
BackupPath                  : {SitePathParent}\{siteName}_snapshots
ContinueSyncOnFailure       : False
CanAddExcludedProviders     : False
NumberOfBackups             : 5
Enabled                     : False
SiteName                    : Default Web Site
CanSetEnabled               : False
CanSetNumberOfBackups       : False
```

---

PS> Get-BackupSettings

```
CanSetContinueSyncOnFailure : False
ExcludedProviders           : {appPoolEnable32Bit, setAcl, appPoolPipeline, createApp...}
BackupPath                  : {SitePathParent}\{siteName}_snapshots
ContinueSyncOnFailure       : False
CanAddExcludedProviders     : False
NumberOfBackups             : 5
Enabled                     : True
SiteName                    :
CanSetEnabled               : False
CanSetNumberOfBackups       : False
```

Comment: Could you share code or config ? How did you configure this backup ?

Comment: pretty much I followed instruction from http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups